# Show multiple errors by toastr

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, toastr

i'm trying to show multiple **error messages** in view by toastr , for user register page.

I passed a list of error messages to View with TempData["errors"]

**but i don't know how to show a list of string (for errors)**

I did this for a **successful** message and the code is as follows

register.cshtml

```
@if (TempData["success"] != null)
    {
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var message = '@(TempData["success"])';

        toastr.options = {
            "rtl": true,
            "closeButton": false,
            "newestOnTop": false,
            "progressBar": false,
            "positionClass": "toast-top-left",
            "preventDuplicates": true,
            "onclick": null,
            "showDuration": "300",
            "hideDuration": "1000",
            "timeOut": "5000",
            "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
            "showEasing": "swing",
            "hideEasing": "linear",
            "showMethod": "fadeIn",
            "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
        };

        toastr.success(message);


    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is that:

You could turn the list to string in your controller as follow:

```
var err = new List<string>() { "error1", "error2", "error3" };
var er = string.Join(",", err.ToArray());
 TempData["errors"] = er;
```

then replace ","with    `<br/>` in your javascript codes as follow :

```
var message1 = '@TempData["errors"]';
var message2 = message1.replaceAll(',', '<br/>');
toastr.error(message2, 'Errors');
```

Result:

[image]

but if you  turn the list to string as follow :

controller:

```
var err = new List<string>() { "error1", "error2", "error3" };
var er1 = string.Join("<br/>", err.ToArray());
TempData["error?"] = er1;
```

Js:

```
var message3 = '@TempData["error?"]';
toastr.error(message3, 'Errors');
```

Result:

[image]

If you want send Individual error message:
controller:

```
var err = new List<string>() { "error1", "error2", "error3" };
TempData["error!"] = err;
```

Js:

```
var message4 = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(TempData["error!"]));
 message4.forEach(x => toastr.error(x));
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping me :)

Answer (score 1):

Toastr supports messages with HTML tags in them. So you can put a `<br/>` tag for a line break.

Try this.

```
TempData["Errors"] = string.Join("<br/>", Errors);
```

Where `Errors` is a collection.

Here is the screenshot

[image: Toastr displaying multiple messages]

Comment: Thank you for helping me :)